# Detectar el segundo caracter del input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero quitar el segundo número siempre y cuando sea 0.

Así me quita el primer 0:

```js
$("#input_1_3").keyup(function (evt) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^0*/, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="input_1_3" type="text">
```

Pero la idea es que si se pone 10, me deje solo el 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Actualización

Para aplicar el reemplazo de caracter relativo a una cantidad limitada de caracteres, puedes implementar lo siguiente:

```js
const cadena = '20360503'
let resultado = cadena

console.log('Valor actual ->', resultado)

const hastaLetra = 2 // Especificamos el límite

resultado = () => {
  const aux = [] // Generamos un arreglo auxiliar para almacenar las nuevas letras
  Array.from(cadena).forEach(letra => {
    aux.push(aux.length <= hastaLetra ? letra.replace(/0/, '') : letra)
  })
  return aux.join('') // Retornamos la cadena nueva recompuesta
}

console.log('Valor final ->', resultado())
```

---

Prueba con `/0/g`:

Puedes revisar la documentación sobre RegExp `g` [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)

Ejemplo:

```js
const cadena = '10'
let resultado = cadena

console.log('Valor actual ->', resultado)

resultado = cadena.replace(/0/g, '')

console.log('Valor final ->', resultado)
```

Comment: Funciona, pero me fije que no deja ingresar ningun 0, osea bien que quita el segundo, pero no deja ingresar un numero como este 2360503.

Comment: Sí, el RegExp `/0/g` implica los ceros de manera global en el string, de allí el uso de `g` al final (g = global). Antes de aplicar la modificación con `replace()` podrías validar el largo de la cadena. El primer 0 lo podrías eliminar simplemente con `replace('0','')`, ya que cuando `replace()` recibe un string como primer parámetro, sólo eliminará la primera coincidencia.